# Contact book read time on Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contacts, android-contacts

I have written the following query to read contacts from a device.

```
private fun getContactPhoneNumbers(resolver: ContentResolver): Map<String, NameAndPhoneList> {
        val startTime = System.nanoTime()
        val map = hashMapOf<String, NameAndPhoneList>()
        val projection = arrayOf(
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI
        )
        val selection =
            "${ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME} NOT LIKE '' and ${ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME} NOT NULL"
        resolver.query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            selection,
            null,
            null,
            null
        )?.let { cursor ->
            if (cursor.count > 0) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    val id: String? =
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID))
                    val name: String? =
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME))
                    val photoUri =
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI))
                    val phone =
                        if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                            val pCur: Cursor = resolver.query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                                arrayOf(id),
                                null
                            )!!
                            val numbers = mutableListOf<String>()
                            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                                val phoneNo: String = pCur.getString(
                                    pCur.getColumnIndex(
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
                                    )
                                )
                                numbers.add(phoneNo)
                            }
                            pCur.close()
                            numbers
                        } else
                            null
                    // take contacts which either have email or phone numbers
                    if (id != null && name != null) {
                        map[id] = NameAndPhoneList(name, phone, photoUri?.let { Uri.parse(it) })
                    }
                }
            }
            cursor.close()
        }
        val endTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime
        Timber.i("$CONTACT_SYNC_PHONE_MAP_QUERY_TIME = $endTime")
        return map
    }

    private data class NameAndPhoneList(
        val name: String,
        val phoneList: List<String>?,
        val imageUri: Uri?
    )
```

this is taking 112877872699 ns (~2 min) for a phonebook of length 6,300 contacts. Is this expected or can we optimize further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for 6,300 contacts (assuming all have a phone) you're making 6,301 queries, which is why it's so slow...

Instead you can benefit from ContactsContract's "[implicit join](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data#columns)" feature, which allows you to get `Contacts.CONTENT_URI` fields when querying over the `Data.CONTENT_URI` table.

So, just query directly over the Data table, get all the phones including the `CONTACT_ID`, `DISPLAY_NAME`, etc. fields, and put it in some map contact-id => data.

Here's sample code in Java that can help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44383937/819355

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you

Comment: not problem, out of curiosity - how fast is the code now?

Comment: Same dataset, it is now 2292 ms.

Comment: Hi @marmor, sometimes this query takes around 9995ms . Is this expected?

Comment: the ContactsContract DB sometimes needs some "warmup" before its able to return ANY query. This may happen more frequently on phones with limited memory, when Android tries to clear some RAM by removing the DB from memory...

Comment: in our app, we do a simple little query when the app launches so that the DB is ready to take queries when we need it to